# Javascript minify on save

Tags: javascript, emacs, minify

I want to add functionality to `javascript-mode` so that, whenever I save a Javascript file on the current buffer, it creates a minified file of it in a directory defined with relative path such as `../foo` with the same file name. How can I do that?

I am using Ubuntu as OS. Is there a good program that I should call in emacs for doing this?

Comment: There are many third party tools which watch files for change and then minify/compress them, you probably want such a tool rather than trying to build this into your editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a function to the `after-save-hook`, but make it specific to javascript mode, add the hook in the `js-mode-hook`.  Also, set `add-hook`'s fourth parameter `LOCAL` to a non-nil value. For example:

```lisp
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
          (lambda () 
            (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'my-minify-function nil t)))

(defun my-minify-function ()
  (shell-command (format "minify %s ../foo/%s" 
                         (buffer-file-name) 
                         (buffer-file-name))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess your `minify` is not an actual command name. Do you have any recommendation that I should use for the shell command? I am using Ubuntu, and found yui-compressor. Do you think  it is good?

Comment: Right, just replace minify with whatever you'd like to use.  YIU and JSMin seem to be the most widely used javascript compressors.  Google's Closure Compiler might be worth looking at as well.